# How can I call a javascript function from server side

Tags: javascript, c#, ascx

I try to call a javascript function from an other c# function but I have an error in my console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: updateState is not defined

**.ascx file**

```
<script>    
    function updateState(){
        console.log("test")
    }   
</script>

<button runat="server" ID="Btn_Modify_state" onserverclick="Btn_Modify_state_Click">
    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
</button>
```

**.ascx.cs file**

```
protected void Btn_Modify_state_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "script", "updateState();", true);
}
```

I don't know how to resolve that issue someone have any idea ?

Comment: In the resulting page, where does `RegisterClientScriptBlock` place its code?  If it's before the function is defined then you probably just need to move the function definition to earlier in the page.

Comment: Specify type <script type="text/javascript">. Some browsers do not work without type attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to do that :

**.ascx.cs**

```
protected void Btn_Modify_state_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", "<script type='text/javascript'>updateState();</script>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to register the script. Try this different approach instead.

```cs
<script runat="server">
  public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Define the name and type of the client script on the page.
    String csName = "updateState";
    Type csType = this.GetType();

    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the client script is already registered.
    if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csType, csName))
    {
      // If not, redefine your script
      var csText = $"
      <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        function updateState(){
          console.log("test")
        }
      </script>";
      cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, csText.ToString());
    }
  }
</script>
```

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock?view=netframework-4.8